# Problemas IF-ELSE

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte código, para procurar uma determinada numeração e verificar se existe. Na variável STR é enviado um texto com números.

```
function verifica(str) {
if (str.match = '/\d\d\d\d\d\.\d\d\d\d\d')  {
    var old = str.match(/\d\d\d\d\d\.\d\d\d\d\d/);
    result = 1;
}

else if (str.match = '/\d\d\d\d\d\.\d\d\d')  {
    var old = str.match(/\d\d\d\d\d\.\d\d\d/);
    result = 2;

} }
```

Ele não está respeitando essas regras, ele só respeita o if, o else IF não respeita. O que pode estar errado ?

Comment: Provavelmente ele está respeitando, mas as regras não são as que dariam o resultado você espera. Poderia por um exemplo prático de como o problema se manifesta?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Têm dois problemas no seu código.

**O primeiro problema** é que quando quer comparar duas variáveis tem de usar o `==`, ou `===`. O que você usa é uma atribuição `=`, e isso não compara nada. Usando somente `=` vai fazer a variável à esquerda ficar com o valor que está na direita. Na verdade quando usa o `=` está a re-escrever a função `.match()`. Ou seja, o `.match()` passa a ter o valor que lhe atribuío e deixa de funcionar...

**O segundo problema** é a maneira como usar o `.match()`. Eu presumo que você quer usar o `if` no caso da `str` ter um certo conjunto de caracteres. Aí só precisa usar algo como `str.match(/[1-2]/)`. Isto só por sí já retorna o que você precisa para usar no if. Por exemplo:

```
var str = '1233';
str.match(/[1-2]/);   // dá verdadeiro no if, mais exatamente ["1"]
str.match(/[1-2]/g);  // dá verdadeiro, mais exatamente ["1", "2"] pois usa o "g" no match que retorna não só o primeiro encontrado
```

Assim o que você deve usar é somente:

```
if (str.match(/\d\d\d\d\d\.\d\d\d\d\d/)) {
```

Uma vez que quer atribuír novo valor à variável `old`, e lembrando que uma atribuíção com `=` retorna um valor se não usar o `var` **então o seu código poderia ser**:

```
function verifica(str) {
    var old;
    if (old = str.match(/\d\d\d\d\d\.\d\d\d\d\d/)) {
        result = 1;
    } else if (old = str.match(/\d\d\d\d\d\.\d\d\d/)) {
        result = 2;
    }
    return result; // isto acrescentei eu, para a função retornar um valor
}
```

Comment: Pensei em "consertar" para `exactamente`, mas acho que você está abrasileirando seu português, *entonces* não mexi ;)

Comment: @brasofilo haha :) Isto de emigrar para a Suécia e participar aqui onde a maioria é brasileira em os seus _side effects_ :)

Comment: Perfeito a resposta @Sergio, obrigado!

Comment: @Sergio, aproveitando a pergunta, você sabe como posso detectar quebra de linha na string ? Exemplo: (/\d\d\d\d\d\.\d\d\d\d\d/) Depois do "." tem um ENTER..?

Comment: @user7605 `\n` pode ser usado para novas linhas.

Comment: @Sergio, no caso eu usaria assim: /\d\d\d\d\d\n.\d\d\d\d\d/ ?